# Why is our Quartz job executing 15 minutes after its corresponding Trigger fires?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

We've recently rolled out a new Java/Spring/Quartz/MyBatis stack to handle our large, data-intensive jobs. Mostly it's been working well, but we've noticed something interesting.

We have a pair of similar jobs that run once a day, a half hour apart. Each performs the same business logic, executing over its own discreet type of users in our database. The jobs have run successfully every day since we released them to production (about a week or so ago). But on two separate occasions, our logs have shown that the trigger had fired right on time, but the actual job didn't execute until 15 minutes later. Once it was the first trigger/job that exhibited this behavior, and once it was the second.

Our logs are written out by the GlobalTriggerListener and GlobalJobListener, as well as periodically by the business logic performed by the job itself, and they all indicate that, on those days, the job ran 15 minutes after the trigger fired. There are no indications whatsoever of any errors occurring around that time.

Below is from our spring/quartz context XML file:

```
    <bean name="AnnualXXXRenewals" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.aaa.cron.base.TaskFactory" />
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="taskClassName" value="com.aaa.cron.tasks.AnnualRenewalTask" />
            <entry key="arg.mode" value="xxx" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="AnnualYYYRenewals" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.aaa.cron.base.TaskFactory" />
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="taskClassName" value="com.aaa.cron.tasks.AnnualRenewalTask" />
            <entry key="arg.mode" value="yyy" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Daily Trigger 8 PM PST (3AM GMT)-->
<bean id="dailyTrigger0800PM" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="AnnualXXXRenewals"/>
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 13 ? * * *"/>
</bean>

<!-- Daily Trigger 8:30 PM PST (3:30AM GMT)-->
<bean id="dailyTrigger0830PM" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="AnnualYYYRenewals"/>
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 30 13 ? * * *"/>
</bean>

<bean id="schedulerFactory"
    class="com.aaa.wrapper.spring.UpdatingSchedulerFactoryBean"
    lazy-init="false">

    <property name="configLocation"
        value="classpath:com/aaa/config/quartz.properties" />
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
    <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext" />
    <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true" />

    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref bean="transactionManager" />
    </property>

    <property name="jobFactory">
        <bean class="com.aaa.wrapper.spring.AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory" />
    </property>

    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="AnnualXXXRenewals" />
            <ref bean="AnnualYYYRenewals" />
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="dailyTrigger0800PM" />
            <ref bean="dailyTrigger0830PM" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And below is from our quartz.properties:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true

#org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=true
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true

# Vendor-specific; MySql uses StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate

# Needed to manage cluster instances
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=AAA_SCHEDULER

org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export=true

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 2
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true

# Job and Trigger Listener
org.quartz.jobListener.GlobalJobListener.class = com.aaa.cron.base.GlobalJobListener
org.quartz.jobListener.GlobalJobListener.name = GlobalJobListener
org.quartz.triggerListener.GlobalTriggerListener.class = com.aaa.cron.base.GlobalTriggerListener
org.quartz.triggerListener.GlobalTriggerListener.name = GlobalTriggerListener
```

Other info: Our server is set to UTC time. The jobs have been taking a matter of seconds to run. The jobs are clustered, currently across 5 Tomcat instances.

Has anyone run into anything like this before? So far it's not caused any problems, but it would be good to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Have you considered adding logging to understand what's going on in that 15 minutes period? Besides, don't you have an extra `*` in your cron expression?

Comment: @snicoll, I've definitely considered adding more logging... except the 15 minute lag occurs between the TriggerListener.triggerFired() and JobListener.jobToBeExecuted(). We have no code that executes between those points, and I don't think there's any way to insert any. Although maybe raising Quartz's logging level would help; we'll try that. Oh, and I'll double-check the cron expression. I *think* it's okay, but trying different values might help us figure out what's up.

Comment: something blocking the jobs for that long as the trigger is firing ok (is a backup running at the saem time or something)...

Comment: Try increasing  thread count.